# SQL Query: Number of channel_views and clicks by dancer_name in the last 7 days

Tags: mysql, sql

I am struggling to visualize this query I am supposed to make. I feel like I am supposed to join two tables together, but I am lost on what to use to fully connect the data together.

**`Channel_Statistics` Table**

I see that `channel_views` and `clicks` are linked to `channel_id`.

**`Video_Channel` Table**

`channel_dancer_id` is linked to `channel_id`. `channel_dancer_id` is the fk for `dancer_id` in the `Dancers` table.

**`Dancers` Table**

`dancer_id` is linked to `dancers_name`.

```
    CREATE TABLE Dancers (
      dancers_id int NOT NULL,
      dancers_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (dancers_id)
    ); 

    CREATE TABLE Video_Channel (
      channel_id int NOT NULL,
      channel_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      channel_dancer_id int,
      PRIMARY KEY (channel_id),
      FOREIGN KEY (channel_dancer_id) REFERENCES Dancers(dancer_id)
    );

    CREATE TABLE Channel_Statistics (
      channel_id int NOT NULL,
      _date date,
      channel_views int,
      clicks int,
      country varchar(255),
      FOREIGN KEY (channel_id) REFERENCES Video_Channel(channel_id)
    );
```

What I've tried

```
SELECT COUNT(Channel_Statistics.channel_views), COUNT(Channel_Statistics.clicks), Dancers.dance_name
FROM Channel_Statistics
INNER JOIN Video_Channel ON Channel_Statistics.channel_id=Video_Channel.channel_id
INNER JOIN Dancers ON Video_Channel.channel_dancer_id=Dancers.dancer_id
WHERE _date > NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
GROUP BY Dancers.dancer_name;
```

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, but I don't think I am calling the right things. I can post it if you want

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i posted it if u want to see

Comment: Your query does not actually look very far off.  What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You'r almost near to the correct query. use `between` to get interval -7 day

```
select count(t3.channel_views), count(t3.clicks), t2.dance_name
from Video_Channel t1
join Dancers t2 on t2.dancers_id= t1.channel_dancer_id 
join Channel_Statistics t3 on t3.channel_id = t1.channel_id
where _date between now() - interval 7 day and now() 
group by t2.dance_name
```

Comment: thank you! sorry, did u mean SELECT COUNT(Channel_Statistics.channel_views), COUNT(Channel_Statistics.clicks), Dancers.dance_name (i think it was from my own typos too). t1 is the dancer table.

Comment: t1 is the video channel

Comment: ah, i dont understand, why is t1 the video channel?

Comment: yes t1 seems to be your main table. since it has foreign keys from dancer and statistics.

Comment: but either way, it should give same results, since you are using inner join

Comment: for this: select count(t3.channel_views), count(t3.clicks), t2.dance_name
from Video_Channel t1 why are you selecting from this table even though channel_views and dance_name are not from video_channel table?

Comment: thank you, sorry im just confused about the wording of the query since we were not taught to label it as t1 and such

Comment: shorter the alias, the better.

Comment: i normally use t1, t2, t3.. you can also use vc, cs, d for your tables, but sometimes there are some tables that may sound same abbreviation, so i rather use t1, t2, t3, t4..

Comment: t1 = video channel, t2 = dancers, t3 = channel statistics

Comment: t2 doesnt have a channel_dancer_id, did u mean t1?